# Why does a failing Iterator filter get stuck?

Tags: scala

Scala's `Iterator` type is, to my understanding, a lazy traversal over a possibly-infinite sequence. E.g.,

```
scala> Iterator continually 0 take 3 foreach println
0
0
0
```

Now according to https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.8/src/library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala#L504 , filtering an iterator defers evaluation by creating another iterator which will do the filter on traversal. E.g.,

```
scala> Iterator continually 0 filter 0.==
res0: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator
```

This returns almost instantly. However, filtering with a predicate that can never be true, seems to go into an infinite loop. E.g.,

```
scala> Iterator continually 0 filter 1.==
```

What's the difference here? Shouldn't they both be doing the same thing, i.e. creating and immediately returning a new `Iterator`?

Comment: They both return Iterator[Int] = <iterator> (scala 2.12.8, java 11.0.1)

Comment: Here is the [broken code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blame/390552d379a6bc34cf770cc164ba46bf17c08f67/src/library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala#L1425). And here is what happened to it just few months ago: [repaired code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blame/38cd84d976880eab16af17a44d186bbddcd554f2/src/library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala#L1425).